# Read multiple digits from 4x4 keypad using raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, lcd, keypad

I am doing some attendance related project. Where I am using 4x4 keypad and a LCD display. So the question is, How can I read more than one number from a 4x4 matrix keypad?. 
I am using pad4pi library. Where I am allowed to read only single number or digit at a time. Now I want to read a number like 1234 or 12345. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for showing me. That code isn’t going to do anything. You have to actually do something with the stored data structure after registering keys.

For example:

```
#change store key function to do something on submission of a certain key that indicated send, will use pound for example.
def store_key(self,key):
     If(key==‘#’):
          #im printing but you should do whatever it is you intend to do with the sequence of keys. 
          print(self.pressed_keys)
     else:
          self.pressed_keys.append(key)
```

That code will print the internal data structure on # being pressed. Of course I’m assuming the key passed on is a string, but I don’t really know I’m not familiar with the library.

Comment: Hey csevier, thanks you so much for your reply. I thought there is no clear() function for list in python. And also I need a digits or strings, not like list. So change the code like below. Now its working like, how i need. Thank you kindness and understanding my little brain. :)

Comment: hi csevier, I have another problem, how can i call other functions using " 
keypad.registerKeyPressHandler(keys.store_key) ". Here is the link for pad4pi library,if you need reference: https://github.com/brettmclean/pad4pi

Comment: Hey Mohan, I really like helping you, but additional questions should probably be facilitated through separate posts. That helps others find and get help as well. If you dont mind selecting an answer for this one, you could link me another stack overflow post with your new question.

Comment: Ok. I got for now. Next time I'll post as new questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a sequence of keys could be facilitated by using a data structure to store the pressed values. And then clearing it when you need to reset.

```
class KeyStore:
    def __init__(self):
        #list to store them
        self.pressed_keys = []

    #function to add to list
   def store_key(self,key):
       if(key==‘#’):
      #im printing but you should do whatever it is you intend to do with the sequence of keys. 
      print(self.pressed_keys)
 else:
      self.pressed_keys.append(key)

    #function to clear list
    def clear_keys(self):
        self.pressed_keys.clear()

keys = KeyStore()

# store_key will be called each time a keypad button is pressed
keypad.registerKeyPressHandler(keys.store_key)
```

Comment: Hi csevier, thanks for your response. But when i tried above code, the code do nothing.The program terminating with in no time after I run the code in terminal.

Comment: Could you show me your repl interaction? Or are you running it via a .py file?

Comment: I think I might understand the confusion. The print was an example of how it might be used. It’s going to print an empty list of you just run this. You are going to have to press keys and do something with it on some other event.

Comment: Yes I am running it via .py file. And if Im using whille loop like below Im getting infinite loop printing the first pressed button.
while(1):
 for key in keys.pressed_keys:
  print(key)

Comment: Hey csevier i just posted my code, can you please check it once.

Answer (score 0):

I did this but still I am stucked

```
from pad4pi import rpi_gpio
import time


# Setup Keypad
KEYPAD = [
        ["1","2","3","A"],
        ["4","5","6","B"],
        ["7","8","9","C"],
        ["*","0","#","D"]
]

# same as calling: factory.create_4_by_4_keypad, still we put here fyi:
ROW_PINS = [16, 20, 21, 5] # BCM numbering; Board numbering is: 7,8,10,11 (see pinout.xyz/)
COL_PINS = [6, 13, 19, 26] # BCM numbering; Board numbering is: 12,13,15,16 (see pinout.xyz/)

factory = rpi_gpio.KeypadFactory()

# Try keypad = factory.create_4_by_3_keypad() or 
# Try keypad = factory.create_4_by_4_keypad() #for reasonable defaults
# or define your own:
keypad = factory.create_keypad(keypad=KEYPAD, row_pins=ROW_PINS, col_pins=COL_PINS)


class KeyStore:
    def __init__(self):
        #list to store them
        self.pressed_keys =[]

    #function to add to list
    def store_key(self, key):
        self.pressed_keys.append(key)

    #function to clear list
    def clear_keys(self):
        self.pressed_keys.clear()

keys = KeyStore()

# store_key will be called each time a keypad button is pressed
keypad.registerKeyPressHandler(keys.store_key)
for key in keys.pressed_keys:
    print(key)

try:
    while(True):
        time.sleep(0.2)
except:
    keypad.cleanup()
```

But its not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code according to changes.

```
from pad4pi import rpi_gpio
import time


# Setup Keypad
KEYPAD = [
        ["1","2","3","A"],
        ["4","5","6","B"],
        ["7","8","9","C"],
        ["*","0","#","D"]
]

# same as calling: factory.create_4_by_4_keypad, still we put here fyi:
ROW_PINS = [16, 20, 21, 5] # BCM numbering; Board numbering is: 7,8,10,11 (see pinout.xyz/)
COL_PINS = [6, 13, 19, 26] # BCM numbering; Board numbering is: 12,13,15,16 (see pinout.xyz/)

factory = rpi_gpio.KeypadFactory()

# Try keypad = factory.create_4_by_3_keypad() or 
# Try keypad = factory.create_4_by_4_keypad() #for reasonable defaults
# or define your own:
keypad = factory.create_keypad(keypad=KEYPAD, row_pins=ROW_PINS, col_pins=COL_PINS)


class KeyStore:
    def __init__(self):
        #list to store them
        self.pressed_keys =''

    #function to clear string
    def clear_keys(self):
        self.pressed_keys = self.pressed_keys.replace(self.pressed_keys,'')

    def store_key(self,key):
        if key=='#':
            #printing the sequence of keys.
            print(self.pressed_keys)
            self.clear_keys()
        else:
            self.pressed_keys += key

keys = KeyStore()

# store_key will be called each time a keypad button is pressed
keypad.registerKeyPressHandler(keys.store_key)


try:
    while(True):
        time.sleep(0.2)
except:
    keypad.cleanup()
```